# Split Data from each cell of one selected column from Dataframe Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to split a String into two parts and save each part in one variable just like in this example :

```
(age,price) =  "32,150".split(',')
```

In my case  I have a Dataframe that contains a list of one column and many rows

```
"GET url"
"POST url"
...
```

[image]

When I try to do the same thing in my dframe I have an error saying that 'Split' is not an attribute of (dframe):

```
(method, url) = Request.split(' ')
```

[image]

Can you please help me have a list of methods and urls in two separated Lists or Tuples.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
Request['col_name'].str.split(' ')
```

Example:

```
In [100]: Request
Out[100]:
                               req
0         GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
1              GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1
2      POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1
3  GET /sitemap_index.xml HTTP/1.0
4   GET /post-sitemap.xml HTTP/1.0
5   GET /page-sitemap.xml HTTP/1.0

In [101]: Request['req'].str.split(' ')
Out[101]:
0           [GET, /robots.txt, HTTP/1.1]
1                [GET, /blog/, HTTP/1.1]
2        [POST, /wp-login.php, HTTP/1.1]
3    [GET, /sitemap_index.xml, HTTP/1.0]
4     [GET, /post-sitemap.xml, HTTP/1.0]
5     [GET, /page-sitemap.xml, HTTP/1.0]
Name: req, dtype: object
```

expanding into columns:

```
In [102]: Request['req'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
Out[102]:
      0                   1         2
0   GET         /robots.txt  HTTP/1.1
1   GET              /blog/  HTTP/1.1
2  POST       /wp-login.php  HTTP/1.1
3   GET  /sitemap_index.xml  HTTP/1.0
4   GET   /post-sitemap.xml  HTTP/1.0
5   GET   /page-sitemap.xml  HTTP/1.0
```